# Overriding methods using Javascript module pattern

Tags: javascript, overriding, virtual-functions

I've got a browser addon I've been maintaining for 5 years, and I'd like to share some common code between the Firefox and Chrome versions.

I decided to go with the [Javascript Module Pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth), and I'm running into a problem with, for example, loading browser-specific preferences, saving data, and other browser-dependent stuff.

What I'd like to do is have the shared code reference virtual, overrideable methods that could be implemented in the derived, browser-specific submodules.

Here's a quick example of what I've got so far, that I've tried in the Firebug console, using the Tight Augmentation method from the article I referenced:

```
var core = (function(core)
{
    // PRIVATE METHODS
    var over = function(){ return "core"; };

    var foo = function() {
        console.log(over());
    };

    // PUBLIC METHODS
    core.over = over;
    core.foo = foo;

    return core;
}(core = core || {}));


var ff_specific = (function(base)
{
    var old_over = base.over;

    base.over = function() { return "ff_specific"; };

    return base;
}(core));

core.foo();
ff_specific.foo();
```

Unfortunately, both calls to foo() seem to print "core", so I think I've got a fundamental misunderstanding of something.

Essentially, I'm wanting to be able to call:

```
get_preference(key)
set_preference(key, value)
load_data(key)
save_data(key, value)
```

and have each browser do their own thing. Is this possible? Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript functions have "lexical scope". This means that functions create their environment - scope when they are defined, not when they are executed. That's why you can't substitute "over" function later:

```
var over = function(){ return "core"; };

var foo = function() {
    console.log(over());
};
//this closure over "over" function cannot be changed later
```

Furthermore you are "saying" that "over" should be private method of "core" and "ff_specific" should somehow extend "core" and change it (in this case the private method which is not intended to be overridden by design)

Answer (score 1):

you never override your call to foo in the ff_specific code, and it refers directly to the private function over() (which never gets overridden), not to the function core.over() (which does).

The way to solve it based on your use case is to change the call to over() to be a call to core.over().

That said, you're really confusing yourself by reusing the names of things so much, imo.  Maybe that's just for the example code.  I'm also not convinced that you need to pass in core to the base function (just to the children).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. I'd forgotten I couldn't reassign closures after they were defined. I did figure out a solution.

Part of the problem was just blindly following the example code from the article, which meant that the anonymous function to build the module was being called immediately (the reusing of names Paul mentioned). Not being able to reassign closures, even ones that I specifically made public, meant I couldn't even later pass it an object that would have its own methods, then check for them.

Here's what I wound up doing, and appears to work very well:

```
var ff_prefs = (function(ff_prefs)
{
    ff_prefs.foo = function() { return "ff_prefs browser specific"; };

    return ff_prefs;
}({}));


var chrome_prefs = (function(chrome_prefs)
{
    chrome_prefs.foo = function() { return "chrome_prefs browser specific"; };

    return chrome_prefs;
}({}));


var test_module = function(extern)
{
    var test_module = {};

    var talk = function() {
        if(extern.foo)
        {
            console.log(extern.foo());
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("No external function!");
        }
    };

    test_module.talk = talk;

    return test_module;
};


var test_module_ff = new test_module(ff_prefs);
var test_module_chrome = new test_module(chrome_prefs);
var test_module_none = new test_module({});

test_module_ff.talk();
test_module_chrome.talk();
test_module_none.talk();
```

Before, it was running itself, then when the extension started, it would call an init() function, which it can still do. It's just no longer an anonymous function.

Comment: Using of "new" keyword before test_module is not needed. You are not using "test_module" as a "construction function" you are just returning an object